# Firefox Add-on SDK: how to make Panel transparent

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Developing a Firefox Add-on. Anyone can please help to figure out how to make a Panel transparent. 
Here is the code to show a panel:

```
    var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 570,
    height: 250,
    contentURL: require("sdk/self").data.url("test.html")
    });
    panel.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it isn't pretty since sdk/panel.js doesn't seem to expose the raw Panel object in order to tweak/extend or compose a another Panel from the existing one.

Here goes:

(1) Get the source for [sdk/panel.js](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/release/lib/sdk/panel.js) here:  [panel.js](https://raw.github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/release/lib/sdk/panel.js) (raw) or from within sdk folder found in your addon xpi.

(2) Add it to your addon package as a new file.

(3) Change the requires parameters of this cloned file (lines 16-24) so that they point to the correct location from your addon.

example:
change

`const { validateOptions: valid } = require('./deprecated/api-utils');`

to

`const { validateOptions: valid } = require('sdk/deprecated/api-utils');`

(4) Find [line 137](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/release/lib/sdk/panel.js#L137), and modify the variable `css` to your liking.  Like so:

```
...
let css = [
  ".panel-inner-arrowcontent, .panel-arrowcontent {padding: 0;}",  //original css rule
  ".panel-inner-arrowcontent, .panel-arrowcontent  {opacity: 0.50; border-radius: 0.35in;}"  //additional css rules:  semi-transparent panel with rounded borders.
].join(" ");
...
```

(5) Use the modified version of panel.js instead of the one that came with the sdk.

That should be it.  Like I said, it isn't particularly elegant.

Comment: You can also just overwrite the `show` function, instead of duplicating the full source